# iOS How to fetch next row parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I work with DB `Back4app` it's similar like parse.com

I want to load in tap button, next row from Data Base.

Now I fetch the first row to my label and button when user will press next, the application will load new row from DB.

My code for fetch data:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "test")
query.getFirstObjectInBackground{ (objects, error) in
    if error == nil && objects != nil {
        let question: String = objects!["question"] as! String
        let answer1: String = objects!["answer1"] as! String
        let answer2: String = objects!["answer2"] as! String
        let answer3: String = objects!["answer3"] as! String
        let answer5: String = objects!["answer5"] as! String
        self.question = question
        self.answer1 = answer1
        self.answer2 = answer2
        self.answer3 = answer3
        self.answer4 = answer5
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.loadDataToBox()
        }
    } else {
        print("Error")
    }
```

How can I do this? I can't find information about this. I only found how to load to table view, but I don't use table view.

Example:

[image: example]

Comment: Have a look at this to see if it helps.  [parse-com-for-xcode-to-make-simple-app-like-trivia-crack-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182556/parse-com-for-xcode-to-make-simple-app-like-trivia-crack-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so with parse you probably dont want to keep calling the server every single time so what you want to do is get your data append it to and array and then just get the information at each index. There are a lot of ways to do this but I'm going to show a simple way to do this. The more you get into parse you can use PFSubclassing and that is a better way to handle your data but for now just do it like this. Create this as a new class

```
Class QuestionManager{
     var question: String?
     var answerA: String?
     var answerB: String?
     var answerC: String?
     var answerD: String?

}
```

In the first class do this.

```
var questions = [QuestionManager]()
var arrayIndex = 0
let query = PFQuery(className: "test")
query.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects, error) in
if error == nil && objects != nil {
    for object in objects as? [PFObject]{
          self.questions.append(QuestionManager(
          question: object!["question"] as! String,
          answerA: object!["answer1"] as! String,
          answerB: object!["answer2"] as! String,
          answerC: object!["answer3"] as! String,
          answerD: object!["answer4"] as! String

          ))
    }
} else {
    print("Error")
}
```

Then two access it just have the index of the array change

```
self.label.text = questions[arrayIndex].question
```

Each time you add one to the array it will return the next set of questions and answers

If you need clarification let me know

Comment: Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'questions'

Comment: In the second code snippet check the first line that's the declaration for questions

Comment: this error i get - "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Comment: Value of optional type '[PFObject]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: Ok delete the query.findinbackground the whole thing rewrite it and let it auto populate. Check if the error in nil and put the for loo back in there

Comment: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments, problem somewhere here -     question: object!["question"] as? String

Comment: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(QuestionManager)'

Comment: so i fix it, now how i can go to the next question?

Comment: ok so every time you need to go to the next question have the button move the array index up 1 so  arrayIndex += 1